# One line of javascript statement is ignored by execution

Tags: javascript

I have a html and a javascript embedded in it. What does the html and javascript do is:

1. There is a input box on this html page
2. javascript placed a event listener on this input box and grab the input as search
3. deliver this search to the web server and do some computation
4. After the computation, a json object is returned
5. Another part of javasript should interpret this json object, then add certain information onto the existing html

Error happens at step 5, 
The json object returned is:

```
    brand:"AS"
    variants: null
```

The javascript try to interpret can be found following:

```
    query.done(function( data ) {
        var now = new Date();
        var responseTime = now - timeBefore;

        var variants = $("<ol />");
        data.variants.forEach(function(variant) {
            var li = $("<li />");
            var dl = $("<dl />");

            dl.append("<dt>Name:</dt>");
            dl.append("<dd>" + variant.name + "</dd>");

            li.append(dl);
            variants.append(li);
        });
        document.write(variants);
        $("#variants").html(variants);
        $("#response_time").html(responseTime + " ms");
```

When I use firefox to debug it step by step, I found that

```
    document.write(variants);
    $("#variants").html(variants);
```

is jumped over which shouldn't be the case.
Any idea on why this happens?

Comment: That's not valid JSON

Comment: You're trying to write a jQuery object. Not sure if that generates an error but probably it's not doing what you think it does. I would fix that to pass a string to document.write

Comment: @hindmost you are right. that is the Response one can read through firefox develop tools. And the json file is in correct form with content presented in the question

Comment: @ClaudioRedi that document.write is only for testing, can be removed. But the problem is $("#variants").html(variants); is not executed. Do not know why

Comment: Never ever use `document.write` from event handlers. And `html()` is the wrong method, as `variants` is a jQuery collection object. Instead, use (`.empty()`)`.append(variants)`.